# How to work with session.merge in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jpa, merge

I am now experiencing this problem. Using hibernate `merge(Object o)` method, it seems it is not working but the strange thing is on my other code it works. This is my codes looks like:

```
public Player addOrUpdate(Player player){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        if(player.getId() == null){
            id = (Integer) session.save(player);
        }else{
            session.merge(player);
            id = player.getId();
        }
        tx.commit();
     }//catch and finally
}
```

and on my Main Class, I am trying to do this:

```
PlayerDao pDao = new PlayerDao();
Player p = new Player();
p.setId(1);
p.setStatus("Hello");
pDao.addOrUpdate(p);
```

When I look at my database nothing change on my data. From my other code (Using other classes), I just did same and my data was updated successfully.

Comment: what is other code?

Comment: My Other Persistent Class. Like, ```Address``` etc.

Comment: does the persist scenario work?

Comment: persist and saveOrUpdate is not working. I can not detect where is the error.

Answer (score 0):

In general when using `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()` instead of `.getCurrentSession()` you should manually flush the objects.

So try calling this just before the transaction commit:

```
session.flush();
```

Comment: I did your suggestion but still nothing change on my data.

Comment: do you close the session in the finally clause?

Comment: Yes. I always close my session.

Comment: Oh. I see, i found out where is the error. I am trying to persist one of my field whose length is greater than the length i set.